# Best way in java to create a new tree which contains ordered data based on a specific criteria

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

A tree exists which stores earthquake information as objects (contains data such as magnitude, date of earthquake, depth of earthquake). I want to filter the objects based on a certain criteria such as depth of earthquake (ascending or descending) and add each object to a new tree which will be all of the earthquakes ordered based on the specific criteria. I don't wont to sort the same tree every time, but instead have different trees for different filters and then be able to use in order search to obtain a specific earthquake object. Also multiple filters can be used. I don't want the code, but instead the algorithmic thinking that would be used to solve such a problem, specifically how one would go through the original tree and then add the objects into the new one in an ordered way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with a custom comparator (it sorts by the keys' natural ordering by default).

To use it with a custom `Comaparator` you simply pass the comparator into the constructor of the `TreeMap`:

```
    TreeMap<SomeKey, Earthquake> earthquakes =
            new TreeMap<>(new YourCustomEarthquakeComparator());
```

Then, in order to have separate trees that sort the earthquakes in a different order, you just define several comparators that compare different fields of the earthquakes.